# Windows Explorer is blank

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I am using Windows 7 Utlimate x64.

Once a week, or so, when I boot up n the morning and launch Windows Explorer it shows up blank, as the following screen shot show.

[image]

Clicking on my Computer doesn't load anything.

Interestingly, I can go the the Address bar at the top and type in a folder name. This brings up that folder's files and subfolders, but as I drill around the tree of folders on the left only shows the immediate folder and not its siblings. There's no plus icon to expand the folder, etc.

[image]

My usual "solution" is to reboot, which typically brings everything back to normal, but this is a frustrating remedy. Any idea what's going on and how to fix it? Some Googling turned up [this discussion](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/2776-blank-windows-explorer-pane.html), but the remedy was to uninstall a particular piece of software that I don't have installed (Virtual Clone Drive).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your drives aren't being scanned for whatever reason by Windows Explorer.

It could be hardware or driver-related (hence the Virtual Clone Drive thread you cited), so I'd check that your drives are plugged in correctly, and do a full surface scan of your drives (a `chkdsk` won't hurt).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I wonder if it has to do with USB, because this seems to most often happen when/if I have my iPod plugged in.

Comment: That is entirely possible. You'll need to test it a few times to establish a pattern (three times or more).